# Distribute an JS Exell add-in offline using Office JS API

Tags: javascript, excel, add-in, office-js

I want to make a Add-In for my IT team that will populate information using REST. I found out about the Office JS API for excel 2016, but it is unclear how a Add-in will be distributed.

The company I work for is huge, and security is a big thing. Everything has to be on prem. I also don't want want to go through the trouble of hosting it on a web server since we would have to get approval etc.

Is there a way to just give my team the add-in and install it that way? Or is my only option to host it somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Excel Add-in that uses the Office JS APIs is a web application which must be hosted on a web server or in a cloud-based web application hosting service.

If your team is using Windows computers, they could in theory each enable the mini-IIS web server on their computers and host the web application in their own computers. They'd have to remember to start up the server every time they wanted to use the add-in. Bug fixes and updates would have to be distributed to everyone too. I would think that it would be a lot less trouble to get a web server.

Comment: Thank you. I learned about VSTO's so I am making one of those. Easier than the other two options. Thank you for the help.